# Custom Event ID

Tags: exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api

When creating an event in outlook Calendar you get a generated event id and using that you can update any event you have created as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_update) by storing the eventId in some table and use it when updating an event, my question is: Is it possible to set that event Id on your own like in googles calendar [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events) so that I don't need to keep track of the event id because it changes everytime you create/update and creates yet annother column in my database?

Comment: seems like it's not possible to set event id in outlook calendar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `id` of an `event` is a calculated hash value based on its metadata. When an item is moved (date, folder, calendar, etc.) the `id` *will* change.

For tracking, you should use the `iCalUId` property from the [`event`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event). This is a guaranteed unique value that will never change. While you cannot define your own value, this GUID is absolutely safe to store and can be used to recall the `event` from Microsoft Graph using the `$filter=iCalUId eq '{GUID}'` query parameter.

Also, unlike the `id`, the value *is* available (and static) for attendees aswell (i.t. if the attendee is using GMail, Google will maintain the same `iCalUId` value on their end).

Comment: The reason that I want to create my own id when creating the event is when exporting Work schedual from a client to outlook Calendar then I have to make a new column for two tables,I'm worried about the time to processl and I also forgot to mention that I generate "work" scheduals in some cases where users can change an entire week or month and I don't store those values. I could store the "iCalUId" in the tables that I already have and turn the function into worker that maybe is active during the night but I'm worried about the cases where I generate scheduals, I have nothing to go on there

Comment: Btw thanks for the explanation about the eventId, could have been an embarrassing bug report haha, I changed it now to store the `iCalUId` value in the database, feel like [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/event_update) documentation should be updated

Comment: Decided to make a new category for events created with my application, filter on them, delete before posting to outlook, this way I don't need to store any data. hack version but works haha